# SQL with java search for a substring

Tags: java, sql

I have the following SQL line (within a loop):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemName='"+ string.get(1) +"'");
```

`string.get(1)` contains a different string each time the loop goes.
in the current SQL line I will revive only the lines that are equal to `string.get(1)`,
but I'd like to get all lines that `string.get(1)` is a sub string of `itemName`
I know it should go: `%string.get(1)%` however I don't know the exact syntax.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `like`clause of `SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the `LIKE` clause in SQL.**

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
    ("SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemName LIKE '%"+ string.get(1) +"%'");
```

Comment: This is correct but it will be open invitation for `SQL Injection`

Comment: Only if `string.get(1)` gets data directly from the user.

Comment: hey Erick Robertson, thx for reply. the sql line you wrote is being complied however it doesn't return all the lines it should...

Comment: @jeffranz You haven't given me enough information to know why.  Try logging the actual queries being executed and run them manually against the database.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Thats true but except OP, we don't know that.

Comment: @jeffranz Your ResultSet object should have these values.

Comment: @jeffranz if you want to know how many rows returned the you can use `rs.getFetchSize()`. [See here in API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFetchSize())

Answer (score 1):

you mean this?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL LIKE '%SOME_TEXT%';
```